# Spacing within footnote lines

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I would like to ask how can I make the space within a footnote smaller. I managed to make the space between several footnotes smaller, but not *within* a single note, as in the image.

My preamble looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\geometry{margin=2.5cm}
\geometry{margin=2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  %To make horizontal pages
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{trig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.7cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{-0.1cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.67}
```

And I would need the space within this footnote smaller:

```
\begin{document}


The results of the intervention\footnote{In 2014, the national poverty lines were established at CFAF 153,530 per capita per year
or CFAF 421 per capita per day.}.`

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never ever post images of code. How are we suppose to help if we cannot try your code. Thus please post a [Minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that others can copy and test as is

Comment: This is not a minimal example, there is no document here only preamble. The MWE needs to be something complete that others can copy and test as is without having to guess or add anything. Additionally it is not clear from your question what you mean by ''space within this footnote smaller" what space?

Comment: What I meant with this is that my footnote appears in two lines, and I would like the space between both lines to be smaller.

Comment: Then why are you setting a very high baseline stretch in the first place? That applies to all text

Comment: Interestingly the `memoir` class, a replacement for the `book/report` class, actually does not apply the `\baselinestretch` to footnotes. But the standard `article` class does.

Comment: I actually found an easier way: ```\footnote{In 2014, the national poverty lines were established at CFAF 153,530 per capita per year or CFAF 421 per capita \\[-0.2cm]per day.}.```

Comment: You could always use `\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\footnote{\def\baselinestretch{1.0)#1}`, or even redefine \footnote using \let (trickier).